# LinqDataSource is showing Error in DotnetNuke Module

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke-module

When I am Select Page Setting Option in DNN below error is showing.

**Error:**
A critical error has occurred. Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for the data source 'LinqDataSource1' and one could not be inferred from the request URL. Make sure that the table is mapped to the dats source, or that the data source is configured with a valid context type and table name, or that the request is part of a registered DynamicDataRoute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here http://dnnlinqtosqladapter.codeplex.com/ and download sql Model adapter and follow the steps and it can solve your problem.

Try it and let me know about.